# HTML - Reproducing and applying unique ID's for a <div> within a <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created a custom div item with ID "Card".

Card also has another div with ID "Collapsible" with custom text that calls for the Collapsible ID.

Both the Card and Collapsible need their own custom ID's as I want to  reproduce the "Card" item upon request and have it function correctly.

To be honest, I'm completely new to this, so I'm having trouble trying to get this to work as wanted.

I'm currently using the following JS code to produce a new "Card" element:

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById("Card");
document.body.appendChild(myDiv.cloneNode(true));
document.body.appendChild(myDiv.cloneNode(true));
```

The problem, is that even though "Card" is reproducing correctly, "Collapsible" is not, it still refers to the previous "Collapsible" objects.  If I manually rename the "Collapsible" ID in every card element, it works.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Everything that I've researched points me to using some sort of Javascript function, but I have yielded no results on how to apply a custom ID to a DIV within another DIV, AND how to refer to those Unique ID's.

Please let me know if any of that was confusing, and I'll do my best to clear up any misunderstandings.  Thanks guys!

```js
var myDiv = document.getElementById("Card");

document.body.appendChild(myDiv.cloneNode(true));
document.body.appendChild(myDiv.cloneNode(true));
```

```css
.wrap-collabsible {
  /* Controls the base label's size and appearance */
  margin-bottom: 1.2rem 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 40%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 70%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) 100%), url("https://help.opera.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2018/03/Help_thumb_security@1x.png");
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  border-radius: 15px;
  position: relative;
  
}

input[type='checkbox'] {
  /* Checkbox flags and enables content from CSS */
  display: none;
}

.lbl-toggle {
  /* Controls the "More Info" label */
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  text-align: bottom;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 7px;
  transition: all .25s ease-out;
}

.lbl-toggle:hover {
  /* Changes color of labels if mouse hovers */
  color: #808080;
}

.lbl-toggle::before {
  /* Arrow location, size, and base transformation */
  content: ' ';
  
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 5px solid currentColor;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  transform: translateY(-2px);
  transition: transform .2s ease-out;
  bottom: 11px;
  right: 105px;
  text-align: right;
}

.toggle:checked+.lbl-toggle::before {
  /* Rotates the arrow. */
  transform: rotate(180deg) translateX(-3px) translateY(2px);
}

.collapsible-content {
  width: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: width .5s ease-in-out;
  
  position: absolute;
  left: 290px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index:-1;
}

.toggle:checked+.lbl-toggle+.collapsible-content {
  width: 400px;
}

.toggle:checked+.lbl-toggle {
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
}

.collapsible-content .content-inner {
  /* Controls the Content inside the popup */
  height: 183px;
  background: rgb(128, 128, 128);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(128, 128, 128), rgba(50, 50, 50));
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(250, 224, 66, .45);
  border-top-right-radius: 7px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  padding-left: 30px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px #000000;
  
}

.bottomright {
  /* Positions any text to the bottom right */
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  right: 16px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div id="Card" class="wrap-collabsible">
  <input id="collapsible" class="toggle" type="checkbox">
  <label for="collapsible" class="lbl-toggle"> 
      <div class="bottomright">
        More Info
      </div>
    </label>
  <div class="collapsible-content">
    <div class="content-inner">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: *Both the Card and Collapsible need their own custom ID's as I want to be able to reproduce the "Card" item upon request and have it function correctly.* This is a common approach for people new to JavaScript because `id`s are easy to get your head around, but as soon as you get to a use case like yours, you begin to see how brittle the use of `id`s is. Don't use them. Instead, this is much more simply solved by relying on CSS classes and element hierarchical position within the DOM

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is clone the node and give it a new ID and then append it. Something like this:

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById("Card");
var clone = myDiv.cloneNode(true);
clone.id = "UniqueId";
document.body.appendChild(clone);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you probably want something like this:

```js
function createCard(id) {
  const card = document.getElementById('card-prototype').cloneNode(true);
  card.id = `card-${id}`;
  return card;
}

[ createCard(1),
  createCard(2),
  createCard(3),
  createCard(4) ].forEach(card => {
    document.getElementById('cards-container').appendChild(card);
  });
```

```css
#card-1 {
  color: red;
}
#card-2 {
  color: green;
}
#card-3 {
  color: blue;
}
#card-4 {
  color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div id="card-prototype">
  <div id="card-collapsible-prototype">
    This is a collapisble.
  </div>
  This is a card.
</div>

<div id="cards-container"></div>
```

The above code will duplicate the card and change the id.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `for` properties of `label`s and `checkbox` elements `id` properties before appending!
This should work:

```js
var myDiv = document.getElementById("Card");
var n=5

for(i=2;i<=n;i++){
  node=myDiv.cloneNode(true)
  node.children[0].id="collapsible"+i
  node.children[1].setAttribute("for","collapsible"+i)
  document.body.appendChild(node);
}
```

```css
.wrap-collabsible {
  /* Controls the base label's size and appearance */
  margin-bottom: 1.2rem 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 40%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 70%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) 100%), url("https://help.opera.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2018/03/Help_thumb_security@1x.png");
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  border-radius: 15px;
  position: relative;
  
}

input[type='checkbox'] {
  /* Checkbox flags and enables content from CSS */
  display: none;
}

.lbl-toggle {
  /* Controls the "More Info" label */
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  text-align: bottom;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 7px;
  transition: all .25s ease-out;
}

.lbl-toggle:hover {
  /* Changes color of labels if mouse hovers */
  color: #808080;
}

.lbl-toggle::before {
  /* Arrow location, size, and base transformation */
  content: ' ';
  
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 5px solid currentColor;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  transform: translateY(-2px);
  transition: transform .2s ease-out;
  bottom: 11px;
  right: 105px;
  text-align: right;
}

.toggle:checked+.lbl-toggle::before {
  /* Rotates the arrow. */
  transform: rotate(180deg) translateX(-3px) translateY(2px);
}

.collapsible-content {
  width: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: width .5s ease-in-out;
  
  position: absolute;
  left: 290px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index:-1;
}

.toggle:checked+.lbl-toggle+.collapsible-content {
  width: 400px;
}

.toggle:checked+.lbl-toggle {
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
}

.collapsible-content .content-inner {
  /* Controls the Content inside the popup */
  height: 183px;
  background: rgb(128, 128, 128);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(128, 128, 128), rgba(50, 50, 50));
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(250, 224, 66, .45);
  border-top-right-radius: 7px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  padding-left: 30px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px #000000;
  
}

.bottomright {
  /* Positions any text to the bottom right */
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  right: 16px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div id="Card" class="wrap-collabsible">
  <input id="collapsible" class="toggle" type="checkbox">
  <label for="collapsible" class="lbl-toggle"> 
      <div class="bottomright">
        More Info
      </div>
    </label>
  <div class="collapsible-content">
    <div class="content-inner">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope this will help!

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to respond!

I took at the look at the code and what you have technically works, however I still have to add in Collapsible2, Collapsible3, and so on for all copies to make it work.  What if I wanted n-number of copies upon request?  I.e. truely being able to generate as many copies as I want/need?

There should be a way to do it where I shouldn't have to make n-number of "CollapsibleN" entities and be able to generate the ID's for them...i will eventually want to put information in each of these cards and will need a way to be able to target them.

Comment: @Tsiaris I edited my answer, and now just change the value of `n` variable to set the number of cards! (In the example `n=5`)